Python changing the value of a variable in one array using a value in another array
I am attempting to reverse the angle if the phase speed is negative and then switch the phase speed from negative to positive.
If the phase speed is negative, reverse the angle, and take the absolute value of the phase speed. This is what I have tried and it does not change the values.
upwardGBPA = upwardtest['Propagation direction [deg N from E]'] * np.pi/180
upwardGBPS = upwardtest['Ground-based phase speed [m/s]']
for i,j in zip(upwardGBPS, upwardGBPA):
    if i < 0:
        j = j + np.pi
        i = abs(i)


Iterate over an index into the arrays and set values like e. g. upwardGBPA[index] = abs(upwardGBPA[index]). After receiving the values, i and j aren't connected in any way to the source of their values (the arrays).

some rules when you work with numpy: avoid for loops, and use numpy functions over regular python ones (ie. np.abs will be far more efficient than abs). to avoid the for loop, just select all negative indices at once and voilà
negative_indices = upwardGBPA < 0
upwardGBPS[negative_indices] = upwardGBPS[negative_indices] + np.pi
upwardGBPA[negative_indices] = np.abs(upwardGBPA[negative_indices])


Thank you! I knew there was an easy way.
